# Parallels VM: Is there a way to run a script on the host when launching a VM?

Tags: parallels

My Parallels VM is configured to use some network services on the host mac via the virtual network, but as the virtual network is not up when the mac host's services are started at boot they aren't listening on the virtual interface and the VM can't connect to them. After starting the VM I have to remember to manually restart those services on the mac host so that they are listening on the virtual network. It's annoying when I forget to do so...

I'd like to automate this process if possible. Is there any way to configure Parallels to run a shell script **on the host** after a VM is started and the virtual network is up? (Suggestions for how to run a startup script on the guest VM are not germane.)

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare script using Automator. Script must be a type "Application". For your purposes, the "Run Sell Script" action is probably the best suited, but you may need something else. After the script is prepared and debugged, you need to move the .app bundle of this script needs to /Applications
Then check in the VM configuration that  Options / Aplications / Share Mac applications with Windows are enabled.
Start the VM (or restart it if it's running).

Please find the element with the scipt name at the Parallels Shared Applications folder in Windows Start menu.
Then please right click on it, choose More / Open file location.

Try to launch script by double-clicking on it.

If the "allow open applications" dilog box is appeared, please select "Always Allow".

Press Cmd+R, type "shell:startup", then press OK and copy the element with the script name from the previously opened window to the new appeared window.

That's it.
Now, every VM startup, a script will be launched on the host.